# Docker /dist output not mounted into host directory

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, monorepo

I have recently added Docker to my javascript monorepo to build and serve a particular package. Everything is working great, however I did not succeed to make the contents under *./packages/common/dist* available to the host directory under *./common-dist* which is one of my requirements.

When running `docker-compose up`, the directory *common-dist* is indeed created on the host, but the files build under *packages/common/dist* on the volume are not appearing; the folder stays empty at all.

#### docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"

services:
  nodejs:
    image: nodejs
    container_name: app_nodejs
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - ./common-dist:/app/packages/common/dist
```

#### Dockerfile

```
FROM node:12-alpine

# Install mozjpeg system dependencies
# @see https://github.com/imagemin/imagemin-mozjpeg/issues/1#issuecomment-52784569
RUN apk --update add \
    build-base \
    autoconf \
    automake \
    libtool \
    pkgconf \
    nasm
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN yarn install
RUN yarn run common:build
RUN ls /app/packages/common/dist # -> Yip, all files are there!
# CMD ["node", "/app/packages/common/dist/index.js"]
```

```
$ docker-compose build
$ docker-compose up # -> ./common-dist appears, but remains empty
```

Could this be related to some permission issues or am I lacking an understanding of what docker-compose actually does here?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: try with a `VOLUME /app/packages/common/dist` in the dockerfile, else I pretty sure its one way i.e hosts/compose declaration just mounts over the top, resulting in an empty dir

Comment: If you use `volumes:` to mount a host directory into a container, this _always_ hides what was in the original image.  (There is no Docker-native option to copy image content to a host directory before container startup.)  This shouldn't be necessary for your application code; delete the `volumes:` to use what's built into the image.